# Retrieve name and value of property has a specific attribute value

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Assume there is an attribute such as:

```
public class ValueAttribute : Attribute
{
  public int Val;
  public ValueAttribute(int val)
  {
    Val = val;
  }
}
```

And it is applied to a class:

```
public class Person
{
  [Value(10)]
  public string FirstName;
  [Value(20)]
  public string LastName;
  [Value(30)]
  public string Age;
}
```

How would I go about efficiently retrieving a `PropertyInfo` (preferably without loop/iteration) of the first occurrence of a property that has `Value(20)`?

Comment: IMHO you could not make it without iterating the properties and checking its individual `Value`

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Comment: Something is going to iterate, if not your code, then framework code. You can cache the attributes after you find them to substantially improve subsequent lookup performance. Also, attributes should be `sealed` in performance critical code.

Comment: Would either of you mind making this into an answer that I can accept?  Cheers

Comment: You have Fields and Not Properties (so you'd want `FieldInfo`s). Also, I do not believe that the order of the fields/properties is guaranteed (it may be an implementation detail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have fields and not properties, so if anything you'd need to get the attributes from a `FieldInfo` object. Second, there is no way to do what you want without some form of iteration. If you are worried about having to look it up each time you could cache the results per type.

```
public static class ValueHelper<T>
{
     private static readonly Dictionary<int, FieldInfo> FieldsByValue;

     static ValueHelper()
     {
         FieldsByValue = typeof(T)
                 .GetFields()
                 .Select(f => new { 
                       Field = f, 
                       Att = f.GetCustomAttribute<ValueAttribute>() 
                  })
                 .Where(c => c.Att != null)
                 .GroupBy(c => c.Att.Val, (val, flds) => new { 
                      Value = val, 
                      Field = flds.First() 
                  })
                 .ToDictionary(c => c.Value, c => c.Field);
     }

     public static FieldInfo GetFieldByValue(int value)
     {
          if (FieldsByValue.TryGetValue(value, out var field)) 
             return field;
          // not found, return null...
          // throw exception, etc
          return null;
     } 

}
```

This can then be used like:

```
var field = ValueHelper<Person>.GetFieldByValue(20);
```

The reflection only occurs once (thanks to the static constructor) and then is cached in a lookup table for further accesses.

If you *really* have properties, then replace `FieldInfo` with `PropertyInfo` and `GetFields` with `GetProperties`.

Note:  I am not sure if the order of fields/properties returned from reflection is *guaranteed*. It may be the case that they are returned in source order, but that may very well be an *implementation detail*.

Comment: I really appreciate how thorough your answer is.  For future reference, starting an answer off with "first of all" and then going on to correct someone may leave them feeling like you are talking down to them like a child.  I'm going to assume that wasn't your intent.  Cheers and thanks for your answer; accepting it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use below code

```
var attr = (ValueAttribute)(typeof(Person)
          .GetField("FirstName")
          .GetCustomAttributes(false)
          .GetValue(0));
Console.WriteLine(attr.Val);
```

Comment: This code assumes that a) all fields have that attribute set and b) there is only one attribute set in those fields. Both things are dangerous assumptions.